# Envío de imagen por AJAX en Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

Necesito enviar mediante `Ajax` una imagen tratada en `Js` con `Canvas`, para lo cual utilizo el siguiente código:

```
function myFunction() {

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(dataURL);

        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },

            type: "post",
            url: "{{ url('/postajax') }}",
            data: {
                $Request:dataURL
            },
            cache: false,
            complete:function(response){
                console.log(response.success);
            }


        });

}
```

La route es la siguiente:

```
  Route::post('/postajax','AjaxController@post');
```

Cuando llego al controlador, el problema es que detecto que entra en el mismo pero no es capaz ni de recoger el Request, ni de si quiera enviar a una nueva vista.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\UsuarioController;


class AjaxController extends Controller {

    public function post(Request $request){

            return view('look');

    }
}
```

Comment: La variable data en el ajax no lleva $Request

Answer (score 1):

En vez de este codigo:

```
$Request:dataURL
```

Coloca:

```
request:dataURL
```

Deberia enviarte la data.

Comment: Lo he corregido, pero no entiendo la razón de que cualquier acción que realice en el controlador aparece en un cuadro JS de alert. Si hago un var_dump de la variable $request, o un return view me lo muestra en un cuadro JS de alert.

Comment: No estaras capturando las respustas en algun lado? Revisa tus archivos donde tienes los jquery y ajax para ver si en algun punto estas capturando datos con un alert?

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo retornar una vista nueva en el controlador después de un envío de Ajax al mismo?